# How to create an SSIS package that will insert records into null cells

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis

My team is working on a project to put together individual files for data entry analysts to work off of. The package I created will drop a file for each individual analyst. There's a "Template" that all of these files are based on. Each file has data validation drop down cells in excel that contain options that agents can choose from. A through T contain the data that is being dropped into the excel file from our SQL server, and U through W contain the columns with data validation that the agents will use to prefill.

My Issue:

Whenever I run the package, the data will only fill in on columns A through T where there is no data validation cells in U through W. SSIS sees A through T as NULL values due to the validation in U through W.

I have tried moving the data to it's own tab, and referencing it on another, but the referencing formulas do not update without manual intervention. Formulas are set to automatic by default, so that is not the issue. Aside from that, I'm not sure how to overwrite the null values in columns A through T.

Package
[image]

Output file:
[image]

Comment: SSIS isn't really the tool for this. I suggest you follow @JessePetronio's advice.

Answer (score 1):

The excel connection manager doesn't allow you to overwrite data in excel. If there is data in the rows of the cells you are trying to write to, the data will be inserted below the last unpopulated row.

I suggest perhaps you use an excel library for much needed flexibility, it will take away all your frustrations. My favorite one to use is NPOI.

Regards,

Jesse Petronio